# Mysql count instances of substring, then order by

Tags: mysql, count, substring

I have a problem in mySQL that goes as follows:

- Count the instances of a substring in a string field in a mySQL database
- Order the results by the number of occurrences of that substring (DESC)

I have never done anything other than rudimentary queries.. I can't find a solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
SELECT (CHAR_LENGTH(str) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str, substr, ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(substr) AS cnt
...
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Yep, looks bloated but afaik there is no any other possible solution.

```
mysql> select (CHAR_LENGTH('asd') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('asd', 's', ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH('s');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| (CHAR_LENGTH('asd') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('asd', 's', ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH('s') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          1.0000 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select host, (CHAR_LENGTH(host) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(host, 'l', ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH('l') AS cnt from user;
+-----------+--------+
| host      | cnt    |
+-----------+--------+
| 127.0.0.1 | 0.0000 |
| honeypot  | 0.0000 |
| honeypot  | 0.0000 |
| localhost | 2.0000 |
| localhost | 2.0000 |
+-----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(LENGTH(`cache`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`cache`, 'substr', ''))) / LENGTH('substr') AS' at line 1

Comment: @zerkms: Can you replace 'asd' with a field name?

Comment: @Alan: added one more sample query

Comment: SELECT cache, (LENGTH(cache) - LENGTH(REPLACE(cache, 'STR', ''))) / LENGTH('STR') AS cnt0 FROM Lnk_Cache ORDER BY SELECT cnt0 DESC LIMIT 25. This is apparently not valid. I don't understand.

Comment: cache is the field name, Lnk_Cache is the table

Comment: @Alan: try to write the same query from the scratch, not copy paste from SO. Seems like it is some unprintable chars that broke query.

Comment: Ahh.. It was an unrelated problem outside the scope of this problem. I believe its working now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: As an east asia user, I want to mention that if both **field** (server side) and **substr** (client/appication side) contains **multibyte characters** and they’re using **different encoding**, LENGTH will get **different length** of *same* string, hence caused the result value be an decimal not an integer, and you can't simply floor or ceil the decimal value to integer, because you don't know the encoding of field on server side. For example: `LENGTH('中文')` in GBK encoding is 4, `LENGTH('中文')` in UTF-8 encoding is 6. So, I’ll use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of LENGTH to calculate length of string.

Comment: This worked great for me. I was wondering though, are there any using regular expressions and RLIKE? I think maybe doing the string manipulation and replacement could be a bit inefficient on values. Using a stored procedure like an answer below is out of the question. This one is the best but curious about other solutions, maybe more efficient.

Comment: @DanFare it's unlikely you can do it better - if you need to manipulate with strings, you need to manipulate with strings :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `subStringCount`//
CREATE FUNCTION `subStringCount` (sequence VARCHAR(1000), word VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT(4)
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE word_length SMALLINT UNSIGNED;

    SET word_length = CHAR_LENGTH(word);

    WHILE (INSTR(sequence,word) != 0) DO
        SET counter = counter+1;
        SET sequence = SUBSTR(sequence, INSTR(sequence,word)+word_length);
    END WHILE; 

    RETURN counter;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Which can be executed by calling:

```
SELECT sum(subStringCount(fieldName,'subString')) FROM  `table` WHERE 1
```