# MySQL: How to order by (-) dash

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How can I `order by` dash?

For instance, I have these data below,

```
page_id   url
1         - a
2         - b
3         --- c
4         --- d
5         - e
6         - f
7         -- g
8         -- h
```

Result that I am after,

```
page_id   url
1         - a
2         - b
5         - e
6         - f
7         -- g
8         -- h
3         --- c
4         --- d
```

If I do this,

```
ORDER by x.url ASC
```

I still get this,

```
page_id   url
1         - a
2         - b
3         --- c
4         --- d
5         - e
6         - f
7         -- g
8         -- h
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My actual SQL,

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IF(grandparentURL REGEXP '^[a-z0-9\-]+$', CONCAT('--- ', url), IF(parentURL REGEXP '^[a-z0-9\-]+$', CONCAT('-- ', url), CONCAT('- ', url))) AS url
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        p.page_id,
        p.url,
        p2.url AS parentURL,
        p3.url AS grandparentURL

    FROM page AS p

    LEFT JOIN page AS p2 
    ON p.parent_id = p2.page_id AND p.page_id != p2.page_id

    LEFT JOIN page AS p3 
    ON p2.parent_id = p3.page_id AND p2.page_id != p3.page_id

    WHERE IF('5' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$', p.page_id != '5', p.page_id IS NOT NULL)
    AND p.url != 'cms' 
) x

ORDER by x.url ASC
```

Comment: Seems to resemble: [MySQL Count Instances of Substring, then Order By...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by).

Comment: How are you defining your columns?  I don't get this result at all.  I get what you want.  See here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51638/1

Comment: @MikeRyan - I have no idea, please see my edit for my actual query. thanks.

Comment: @pst - I'm on `MyISAM` and `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Again, using your query and defining your columns with the `utf8-general-c1` collation, I get what you want:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79873/1  What's the version?  I don't see why might be wrong.

Comment: @MikeRyan - thanks for the help. i'm on 5.5.20, warmserver, i dunno what goes wrong really. maybe my query is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do MULTIPLE order by... FIRST by the position where space is found first all grouped... from that, then sort by the entire URL.  Since the common - b and - a will be in the same grouping, their space keeps them in group "1"... then, from that, the entire URL will force your proper - a, - b, - c, etc

```
ORDER BY INSTR('x.url', ' '), x.url
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, ' '),url
```

The first part orders by the position of the first space within the string

Comment: No, it shouldn't, that is why the actual URL is the second part of the ORDER clause.   You could also use trim(replace(URL,'-','')) as the second part of the ORDER BY clause

Comment: I get this error `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'`

Comment: @lauthiamkok - Try `SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, ' ', 1)`

Comment: @dem - yes it is always a space, not a control code character, see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: @Dems - yes I have tried  `SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, ' ', 1)` still the same though...

Comment: found the problem. I have duplicate columns and it take the first column that is without the dash...