# MYSQL LIKE categories returning wrong query due to %

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a CMS with a bunch of different tags and categories. I obviously use each category as a unique ID and save them in the database like so:

```
cats -> 2,15,115
tags -> 13,33,113
```

That is a simple example.

I am having problems when I want to show related content by a GET variable $cat to use in my query:

```
WHERE cats LIKE '%$cat%'
```

Here is the challenge, if the $cat = '5' , then it returns, 5, 15, 55, 115... and so on. I just need it to match just '5' and nothing else!

I'm sure I am missing something really, really simple.

**EDIT:**
The find_in_set works really well. However, my other challenge is my $GET variable is sometimes like this: `$cat = 150,181`

So how can I use the variable $cat to see if there is just one of those matches ? I want to match either 150 OR 181 against the query ?

Comment: If you are looking for a more finite search that is a little more controllable I would suggest looking into REGEXP in MySQL. It will give you a lot of flexibility as far as searches go. Here is the link to the documentation to get you started: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` since column `cats` has these values `2,15,115`

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET('5', cats) > 0
```

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: SO I can use SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$cat', cats) > 0

Comment: yes, another alternative is `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CONCAT(',', cats, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', '$cat',',%")`

Comment: Ok, another challenge, what if my GET variable was '15,4' how would I use those in my query to look for just one of those cats to match?

Comment: That's not as straight-forward, at least the way I see it.
You can use the query from the following SQL Fiddle as inspiration:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17334.

The method of how to count occurences of substring in string is courtesy of @zerkms, found in this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't help me. Please see my edits in my question above.

Answer (score 2):

If you use LIKE with wildcard character '%' you extend your search all values containing '5' in base of you put your %.

%value% (cointaining)
%value (end with value)
value% (start with value)

You can use like as equal, simply not used %, but I advice you to use equal operator (=)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense as well

Comment: That does make sense, but how to use in my example above. Is that really the most efficient way to do this ? How to differentiated different cats ?