# MySQL Query: limit result respecting substring count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
ROW ID         |   CONTENT
------------------------------------------------
test1          |   foo, foo, foo
test2          |   bar, bar
test3          |   foo, foo
test4          |   foo, foo, foo, foo
```

What I want to achieve is query that gives me the rows but limiting it respecting the occurrences of a substring.

Some examples could be:

- Limit result to 3 "foo" occurrences -> should return test1
- Limit result to 4 "foo" occurrences -> should return test1 and test3
- Limit result to 100 "foo" occurrences -> should return test1,test3, test4
- Limit result to 7 "foo" occurrences -> should also return test1,test3, test4

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

P.S. : I should have mentioned that the ',' can be any string without a predictable length.

Comment: You should change your DB structure and store only 1 value per column.

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by

Comment: I ***highly*** suggest only storing one value per row.  Something like this screams for a link table (or 2).  Or even just having multiple rows in this table.

Comment: I just realized I'm a little confused here.  Why does `limit to 3` not return `test3`?  Why does `limit to 4` not return `test4`?  What is the criteria here?  I don't think I understand what you want this query to return.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ... I had the same confusion...but I assumed that OP means that occurences count must be below the "limit"

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0f8f/11)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ROW ID` varchar(5), `CONTENT` varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ROW ID`, `CONTENT`)
VALUES
    ('test1', 'foo, foo, foo'),
    ('test2', 'bar, bar'),
    ('test3', 'foo, foo'),
    ('test4', 'foo, foo, foo, foo')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE ((LENGTH(CONTENT) - 
        LENGTH(REPLACE(CONTENT, ',', ''))) + 1) < 3
     AND SUBSTRING(CONTENT,1,LENGTH('FOO')) = 'FOO'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0f8f/11/0)**:

```
| ROW ID |  CONTENT |
|--------|----------|
|  test3 | foo, foo |
```

EDIT :

If you are dealing with phrases, it could look like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70557/28)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ROW ID` varchar(5), `CONTENT` varchar(48))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ROW ID`, `CONTENT`)
VALUES
    ('test1', 'foo de foo refe foo'),
    ('test2', 'bar re bar'),
    ('test3', 'foo rer ef foo'),
    ('test4', 'foo rer foo fsdfs foo dfsfe foo')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (LENGTH(CONCAT(' ',CONTENT,' ')) - 
       LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(' ',UPPER(CONTENT),' '), 
                      CONCAT(' ','FOO',' '), '')))
       /(LENGTH('FOO')+2) < 3 AND
       CONCAT(' ',CONTENT,' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ','FOO',' %')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70557/28/0)**:

```
| ROW ID |        CONTENT |
|--------|----------------|
|  test3 | foo rer ef foo |
```

Comment: You forgot to post the SQLFiddle link :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat ... copy/paste mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I should have mentioned that the ',' can be any string without a predictable length.

Comment: But in your case the , is concatenated to `foo` which will look like `foowhatever` if it is something else. If there is always spaces, check my second answer...

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of `foo`s in the list.  This is pretty easy:

```
select t.*
from t
where (char_length(concat(', ', content, ', ')) -
       char_length(replace(concat(', ', content, ', '), ', foo, ', '1234567'))
      ) = 3;
```

The idea is to replace `'foo'` with something that has one fewer character.  However, you might want to be careful with `'foobars'` and `'barfood'` and other strings that could cause a false positive.  So, this version just puts the separators at the beginning and end of the string.

Once you have this information, you can do whatever comparisons you would like.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL unfortunately doesn't have any bulit-in function for what you want to do.  You need something like `SUBSTRING_COUNT`, which doesn't exist.  What you can do is, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427534)` calculate that value.

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT rowid,
(LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, 'foo', ''))) / LENGTH('foo') AS cnt

FROM thetable

HAVING cnt > 0 && cnt < 4;
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10599/7

Comment: I guess this is a bit wrong. When he limits 3, he wants to count 3 occurences of **'foo'**, for example. So, if the first row has 3 **'foo'**, no other row will be returned. In your code, it counts 3 for each row, not for the entire table.

Comment: @LucasHarada: Huh?  I'm confused.  I don't know what you are trying to say.  He said `occurrences of a substring`.

Comment: But these are occurences of a substring on the entire table, not for each row. Check his examples: when he limits by 4, the test 4 doesn't count.