# ordering in rails based on the count of a word present in a single column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named `Vendor`. I have three different models associated with it.

1. Testimonial
2. Service
3. Works

I have to look up each of the tables and list the vendors(limit 5) which have the word "example" most number of times in a column in one of these models. How do I do this in rails?

---

I have something like this

```
Vendor.joins(:testimonials).where("testimonials.content LIKE ?","%example%")
```

I need to find the vendors who has the maximum number of occurrences of the word "example"

Comment: is that column is string type?

Comment: Yes, cosider all the columns as strings with `text` datatype

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by

Comment: BTw your question is a bit misleading: you don't want to group by number of incidences, you want to **order** by number of incidences.

Comment: Sorry I will change it @MaxWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing this. Not sure if my question was asked correctly. I made this with the help of a previous answer by @user3383458

```
vendor = Hash.new
        Vendor.all.each do |v|
            testi_word_count = 0
            service_word_count = 0
            title_word_count = 0
            v.testimonials.each do |testi|
                testi_word_count += testi.content.scan(/#{word_to_search}/).count
                Rails.logger.info "testi_word_count"
                Rails.logger.info testi_word_count
            end
            v.services.each do |service|
                service_word_count += service.name.scan(/#{word_to_search}/).count
                Rails.logger.info "service_word_count"
                Rails.logger.info service_word_count
            end
            v.works.each do |work|
                title_word_count += work.title.scan(/#{word_to_search}/).count
                Rails.logger.info "title_word_count"
                Rails.logger.info title_word_count
            end
            vendor[v]=testi_word_count + service_word_count + title_word_count
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you right now:

```
a=[]
vendors.each do |v|
  c=0
  c=v.testimonial.scan(/example/).count
  if c>0
  a=a.concat([{vendor: v, counts: c}])
end
```

Comment: I think this will output the count whereas I need to order the vendors based on the count of "example" for each of the vendor's testimonial

Comment: Do you need every Vendor, that contains the word `example`??

Comment: The limit should be 5. I need every vendor who has the word example in his testimonial and they are to be ordered by the count of the word example in descending order. Also this to be coupled with the columns services and works. But that can wait as the next iteration if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can count the occurrence of a substring in a string in this way, for example

```
s = "this is a string with an example, example, example"
s.scan(/example/).count  # => 3
```

Comment: I have something like this `Vendor.joins(:testimonials).where("testimonials.content LIKE ?","%example%")` . I need to find the vendors who has the maximum number of occurrences of the word "example"

Comment: By your objection, do you mean that you just want to use sql, and not any post-search ruby code?