# SQL operator IN returns only DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT class, subclass ,weight
FROM classes 
WHERE classes.term in ('this','paper','present','this','and','this','this')
```

The above query returns only distinct values. For example I have the following table:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|class | subclass |  term  | weight |
+-----------------------------------+
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  c   |     d    |  paper |   2    |
|  e   |     f    |  sth   |   1    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

the result I will get is

```
+-----------------------------------+
|class | subclass |  term  | weight |
+-----------------------------------+
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  c   |     d    |  paper |   1    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

what I actually wanted is the following

```
+-----------------------------------+
|class | subclass |  term  | weight |
+-----------------------------------+
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   3    |
|  c   |     d    |  paper |   2    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I there any other way to get all the results without IN "cutting" only distinct values?
The problem is that I cannot change that part: ('this','paper','present','this','and','this','this')
because it is not created by a query. It is a string of words I want to search.

**Edit:**
 - In the original scenario the table contains more than 3000 different words and the actual string is generated by a function I do not have
   rights to access and contains 300+ words with many duplicates.
 - In the original scenario I want to add the weight of the word every
   time it appears in the string

**Edit2:**

The result I expect is to sum the weights every time a term appears in string. 
Expecting results like the following:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|class | subclass |  term  | weight |
+-----------------------------------+
|  a   |     b    |  this  |   12   |
|  c   |     d    |  paper |   2    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does the data contain three rows? If so, then sql is not returning distinct. It is returning all rows that match. Since there are only two rows, it returns two.

Comment: While not entirely impossible, this is a tedious exercise to undertake in SQL.

Comment: you would probably need to break up the string of words, and union the results

Comment: I can't possibly understand the reasoning behind this. Why do you want the row returned four times?

Comment: @NagasimhaIyengar No the data actually has something like 3000+ different rows. the problem is that the string has a lot of duplicates

Comment: @Doon as I have already said I cannot change the string. That string is an example of the original string that contains about 300 or more words with a lot duplicates

Comment: @McAdam331 I want to sum the weights for every word. In the original scenario each word has a weight as a double. That means that when I get that string I want to sum every time the word appears in the string

Comment: well if you have 300 terms with lots of duplicates in the query, but only 1 row in the table with a given term, you are only ever going to get 1 row back.. unless you do something like gordon's answer

Comment: yeah but I don't think is possible to do something like that with 300+ random words. I could create a fuction to create the query every time but it is ugly and a solution I would like to avoid. However that would be my final choice if there is no other solution

Comment: Could you create an sqlfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: You mean for the above example or for the original scenario?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433c5/3/0 here is the sql fiddle for the above example with the sql query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433c5/6 Another one with the sum and the group by. The correct result should be similar with that but in the weight of the first row of the results should be 4 times that (because the term appears 4 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by) on how to count the number of occurrences in a substring:

```
SELECT m.*, (LENGTH('this paper present this and this this') - LENGTH(REPLACE('this paper present this and this this', term, ''))) / LENGTH(term) AS count
FROM myTable;
```

Once you have the number of occurrences for each string, you can multiply that value by the `weight` to get the total, like this:

```
SELECT term, weight * (LENGTH('this paper present this and this this') - LENGTH(REPLACE('this paper present this and this this', term, ''))) / LENGTH(term) AS totalWeight
FROM myTable m;
```

Note that this solution does not take a separated list of words, but concatenates that list into one string.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15bd4/6) example for you.

---

**EDIT**

If you want the sum of weights for all terms in the string, without regard to the terms themselves, you can just adjust the query to use the `SUM()` function, and don't use `GROUP BY` because you want to sum for the whole table:

```
SELECT SUM(weight * (LENGTH('this paper present this and this this') - LENGTH(REPLACE('this paper present this and this this', term, ''))) / LENGTH(term)) AS totalWeight
FROM myTable m;
```

---

**EDIT 2**

A little more explanation for the query based on lengths. You can break it up into multiple parts:

1. `LENGTH('this paper present this and this this')` returns the number of characters in the string you are searching
2. `LENGTH(REPLACE(myString, term))` is the length of the string above, with your term removed. (So, for example of 'this', it's going to be total length 37, subtracting 16 (4 for each occurrence) which will give you 21.
3. By subtracting the second value from the first, you'll get the number of characters in the overall string that are as a result of your value (37 - 21 = 16).
4. Then, it divides it by the length of 'term' to get the number of occurrences. 16 characters, divided by 4 characters in each occurrence means the substring occured 4 times. (16 / 4 = 4). Try these steps again with 'paper' and you will see.

The above procedure is illustrated step by step in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15bd4/13).

Comment: I understand what you mean! But I think this is helpful if I have to look for only one term. I want to calculate the weights for all the terms in the string

Comment: Nope I don't want the total weight of all the words. That could be done really easier than your edit. I want for every term the sum of his weight every time it appears and if the term is in the table with the terms. That means 4*weight_of_term_this , 1*weight_of_term_paper and nothing else.

Comment: That's exactly what my first query does, @Blenikos.

Comment: The only difference might be that my query above also shows '0' counts. If you don't want 0 counts included, adjust your `WHERE` clause to avoid terms that aren't in the string, as shown [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15bd4/7)

Comment: Yes your first query is really close. (I was looking at the second. sorry) It returns the weight and the count but I actually want one column with weight*column. I would try to fix that.

Comment: That's what it does, right? It takes the weight, multiplied by the number of occurrences. The sample data you gave has all weights of 1, try changing the weight of 'this' to 2, and you'll see that my query returned eight. If that's not what you're looking for, I just don't understand. Can you edit your question to show expected results, or are those actually your expected results that are there? @Blenikos

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433c5/10 here is the sql fiddle with your first query and the results. I have also edited (Edit2) the expected results in the above example (actual question)

Comment: @Blenikos the issue is because you didn't use my second query, where you multiply the count by the weight. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433c5/16

Comment: You are right!!!! That's exactly what I wanted (with the WHERE at the end to remove 0) Thanks a lot!! But could you explain a bit what is going on that query??

Comment: @Blenikos no problem, I agree it was a little complex. I have edited my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `join`:

```
select c.*
from (select 'this' as term union all
      select 'paper' as term union all
      select 'present' as term union all
      select 'this' as term union all
      select 'and' as term union all
      select 'this' as term union all
      select 'this' as term
     ) terms left join
     classes c
     on c.term = terms.term;
```

This will work in both MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: Beat me to it. I reached my daily vote cap, but I'll try to remember to come back tomorrow and upvote.

Comment: Nope I cannot do this. The actual string comes with about 300+ words or more and every time is generated from a function that I don't have rights to change in the code so is not that simple. Thanks anyway. I am going to add this information in my question above