# Relevancy MySQL query to replace stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've taken over a project built by my predecessor. That project contains a stored procedure originally taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9100182/439925

Currently this is preventing us from updating MySQL, so i have been attempting to remove it and replace the calls to subStringCount() with an adjustment to the top answer on that question.

```
(( Round (( Char_length(`title`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`title`, 'info', "")) ) / Char_length('info')) * 30 ))  AS `title_score`,
```

The queries are used to count the number of times a search string occurs in a number of fields and then order by the total. Unfortunately i can't get the new query results to match the old one.

The 2 full queries are as follows:

**Old WITH the stored Proc:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `temp`.*,
                       ( `title_score` + `source_score`
                         + `abstract_score` + `authors_score`
                         + `drugs_score` + `uploader_score`
                         + `area_score`
                         + Ifnull(`document_content_score`, 0) ) AS
                       `relevance`
FROM   (SELECT `kb_uploads`.*,
           (( Substringcount(`title`, 'info') * 30 )) AS `title_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`source`, 'info') * 15 )) AS`source_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`abstract`, 'info') * 20 ) AS`abstract_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`authors`, 'info') * 30 )) AS `authors_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`drugs`, 'info') * 20 ))  AS `drugs_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`kb_users`.`name`, 'info') * 20 )) AS `uploader_score`,
           (( Substringcount(`kb_upload_areas`.`name`, 'info') * 20 )) AS `area_score`,
           ( `content_tbl`.`index_score` * 1 ) AS `document_content_score`
    FROM   `kb_uploads`
           LEFT JOIN `kb_users`
                  ON `kb_users`.`id` = `kb_uploads`.`uploader`
           LEFT JOIN `kb_upload_areas`
                  ON `kb_upload_areas`.`id` = `kb_uploads`.`area`
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT `upload`,
                             Sum(`weighting`) AS `index_score`
                      FROM   `kb_search_index`
                      WHERE  `word` = 'info'
                      GROUP  BY `upload`) AS `content_tbl`
                  ON `content_tbl`.`upload` = `kb_uploads`.`id`) AS `temp`
WHERE `is_deleted` = 0
HAVING `relevance` > 0
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

**New WITHOUT the stored Proc:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `temp`.*,
                       ( `title_score` + `source_score`
                         + `abstract_score` + `authors_score`
                         + `drugs_score` + `uploader_score`
                         + `area_score`
                         + Ifnull(`document_content_score`, 0) ) AS
                       `relevance`
FROM   (SELECT `kb_uploads`.*,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`title`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`title`, 'info', "")) ) / Char_length('info')) * 30 ))  AS `title_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`source`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`source`,'info' , "")) ) / Char_length('info')) * 15 )) AS `source_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`abstract`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`abstract`, 'info', "" ) ) ) / Char_length('info')) * 20 )) AS `abstract_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`authors`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`authors`,'info', "")))/Char_length('info')) * 30 )) AS `authors_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`drugs`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`drugs`,'info',"")) ) / Char_length('info')) * 20 )) AS `drugs_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`kb_users`.`name`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`kb_users`.`name`,'info',""))) / Char_length('info')) * 20 )) AS `uploader_score`,
           (( Round (( Char_length(`kb_upload_areas`.`name`) - Char_length(REPLACE(`kb_upload_areas`.`name`,'info', "")) ) / Char_length('info'))* 20 )) AS`area_score`,
           ( `content_tbl`.`index_score` * 1 ) AS `document_content_score`
    FROM   `kb_uploads`
           LEFT JOIN `kb_users`
                  ON `kb_users`.`id` = `kb_uploads`.`uploader`
           LEFT JOIN `kb_upload_areas`
                  ON `kb_upload_areas`.`id` = `kb_uploads`.`area`
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT `upload`,
                             Sum(`weighting`) AS `index_score`
                      FROM   `kb_search_index`
                      WHERE  `word` = 'info'
                      GROUP  BY `upload`) AS `content_tbl`
                  ON `content_tbl`.`upload` = `kb_uploads`.`id`) AS `temp`
WHERE `is_deleted` = 0
HAVING `relevance` > 0
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

There are 2 main issues.

1) Ifnull is not working in the NEW query. The table column contains mostly null instead of 0

2) The relevancy numbers in the new query don't match the numbers in the old one, possibly something to do with IFNULL not working.

The full queries are constructed in PHP, i have left the code out as the logic hasnt changed, only the string concats to replace the Stored Proc.

Comment: Don't use double quotes in a replace statement: `REPLACE(`title`, 'info', "")` change it to `REPLACE(`title`, 'info', '')`

Comment: @JorgeCampos No joy im afraid, still the same problems

Comment: The answer to the other question is a stored *function*, not a stored *procedure*.  It does not make sense that this is "preventing" you from updating MySQL.  In what way is that happening?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Its simply not compatable. The formats for Stored proc's / functions (also in the stored Proc table btw) changed significantly between the version we're currently running (5.1) and 5.6 / 5.7. We could have run the update however any site using the function would have broken. hence the need to fix it before the upgrade.

Comment: I'm sorry, but someone has convinced you of some absolute nonsense, leading you to try to "fix" what isn't broken. The "format" of procs and functions did not change, only the format of one some system tables did... But if MySQL is *correctly* updated from 5.1 to a later version, all of your stored programs will work just fine as they are without modification.  You can typically even successfully fix an incomplete upgrade later: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46108/11651

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It wouldn't be a problem if it wasn't in the global Procs table which is a Mysql 4.* thing iirc