# Select line count from LONGTEXT without using REPLACE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the number of lines in a LONGTEXT field.

I know I can do the following:

```sql
select

(
    CHAR_LENGTH(log_data) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(log_data, "\n", ""))
) / CHAR_LENGTH("\n") as line_count

from client_logs where id = 7;
```

However, using `REPLACE` is insanely slow on un-indexed data, especially when the data can be 100,000 lines long or more. As is it takes ~18 seconds to determine the line count on a LONGTEXT with ~63,000 lines.

Is there any other way to get the number of lines in a LONGTEXT without using this costly procedure?

Edit: Since this was marked as a duplicate, please keep in mind I am specifically asking how to do this **WITHOUT** using `REPLACE`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql count instances of substring, then order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by)

Comment: @NikosM. I don't think it's a duplicate, I'm specifically asking if there is a way to do this *WITHOUT* using `REPLACE`

Comment: all other possible ways to count lines, or substring occurences are even slower

Comment: @NikosM. Well that sucks. Point still stands that this isn't a duplicate, it just doesn't have a solution I feel.

Comment: It is not yet closed as duplicate, it is only a possible duplicate. No rush, maybe someone will answer

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if the text being too long is the problem; I am thinking maybe you can do a one-time activity and break the text and store different lines as different rows instead in a new table. That way counting; and even (as per your previous question), getting pth to qth line would also be fast

Comment: another way would be to count lines before inserting into db (eg in app) and store it as separate field. It is updated whenever text is updated